# Setting width of the action column removing space in material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am new to react and new to material-table.

I think I have a known issue, The problem is my action column in material table is taking too much width and space how do I reduce it??

[image]

As shown in the picture I want to reduce the action column to a minimum. How do I do that?

Here is the code:

```
const columns = [
  { title: 'Sl.No', field: 'ID' },
  { title: 'TDC', field: 'TDC' },
  { title: 'Customer Name', field: 'CustName' },
  { title: 'Supply Plant', field: 'SPCode' },
  { title: 'Cost Impact', field: 'Cost' },
  { title: 'Date', field: 'CreatedOn' },
  
];

<MaterialTable
        title="Request Table"
        columns={columns}
        icons={tableIcons}
        data={this.props.reportList}
        options={{
          paging: true,
          pageSize: 15,
          //tableLayout: 'fixed',
          //whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        }}
        actions={[
          {
            headerStyle: { maxWidth: '20px' },
            padding: '5px',
            icon: tableIcons.Edit,
            iconProps: { style: { fontSize: '10px' } },
            tooltip: 'Delete User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => this.getRowValue(rowData.ID),
          },

          {
            icon: tableIcons.Add,
            tooltip: 'Add Request',
            isFreeAction: true,
            onClick: this.reset,
          },
          {
            // icon: tableIcons.ViewColumn,
            icon: tableIcons.InfoIcon,
            tooltip: 'Add Request',
            isFreeAction: true,
            onClick: this.Info,
          },
        ]}
      />
```

Please help me in this . Please let me know what to do?

Is it something to do with hidden columns?

Comment: did u try defining the width of the other columns?   `{ title: 'Sl.No', field: 'ID', cellStyle: { width: '12%' } }` or try setting `tableLayout: auto`

Comment: Can u please create a sandbox